# use variable in select - tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters

Hi I have procedure which have parameter(@identFormat)

Example

"GUID"

"LotID|FeatureID"

And now I have Select query which should split this and use as columns.
Moreover result should be back combined.

Example:

```
Table: 
Id    LotID   FeatureID
2      1       4
3      4       5
4      2       1
```

and if my @identFormat = "LotID|FeatureID" then it should return

```
Table:
1|4
4|5
2|1
```

Actually I have ncharchar @columns 'LotId + "|" + FeatureId'

Is it possible to use this like this:

Select @columns from Table ?

or using dynamic sql

EDIT:

Unfortunately combination of columns can be different. My purpose is send column names to procedure and select this columns from specific table. This is procedure to save data , but if  something went wrong I must save this unique combination of columns in second table.

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers in T-Sql.

Comment: Is there always just this combination possible or might there be other column names as well?

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers in *any* SQL dialect, not just T-SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately combination of columns can be different.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, it is not possible. You need to select separately and format the output